# Type check for nested generic classes in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have a problem solving following use case in swift, and not sure if it is even possible.

Let's say I have a data structure class using generics - let's call it
    `Container<T>`

Now I have a list of many Container that can be of different types T, e.g.
`Container<A>, Container<B>, Container<A>, Container<C>, Container<C>, ...`

I would like to go through the list, and for each Container find out what the "inner type" is. And I would like to cast to it, if possible.

The possible types for T are not finite, so I cannot have a big switch case testing for each of them.

What I try is something similar to:

```
if value is Container<???> {      <- 1. should match Container with any type (??? stands here for any type)
   let value = value as! Container<???>   <- 2. a cast to the specific Container
   ...
}
```

What ways would be possible to solve 1. and 2.?

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you're wanting to do if @Code Different didn't answer your question already.  Are you wanting to cast to a ContainerA of any T?

Comment: I have edited the question slightly to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch over a value and conditionally cast it to some known possible types (if the case falls through: type conversion successful).

Example:

```
class MyClass : CustomStringConvertible {
    var foo : Int = 1
    var description: String { return "MyClass().foo = \(foo)"}
}

struct Container<T> {
    var myVar : T
}

let value1 = Container<Int>(myVar: 1)
let value2 = Container<MyClass>(myVar: MyClass())
let value3 = Container<String>(myVar: "one")
let value4 = "Foobar"

let values : [Any] = [value1, value2, value3, value4]

for (i, value) in values.enumerate() {
    switch value {
    case let foo as Container<Int>:
        print("Element #\(i+1) is an Int container with .myVar = \(foo.myVar)")
    case let foo as Container<String>:
        print("Element #\(i+1) is a String container with .myVar = \(foo.myVar)")
    case let foo as Container<MyClass>:
        print("Element #\(i+1) is a MyClass container with .myVar = \(foo.myVar)")
    case _: print("Element #\(i+1) is of unknown type.")
    }
}

/* Element #1 is an Int container with .myVar = 1
   Element #2 is a MyClass container with .myVar = MyClass().foo = 1
   Element #3 is a String container with .myVar = one                    
   Element #4 is of unknown type.                                      */
```

---

Note: just as I posted my answer I saw your edit addition:

> *"The possible types for T are not finite, so I cannot have a big
>   switch case testing for each of them."*

So you have an "infinite" number of different types that might be held in this list of yours? In this case, I assume you have no custom actions depending on what is held in the container, in which case I don't see why you need to attempt down casting (since, as per your update in question, you can *always* downcast to some of the "infinite" amount of types).

> *"I would like to go through the list, and for each Container find out
>   what the "inner type" is. And I would like to cast to it, if possible."*

This is equivalent to just finding out the container type and casting to self; the latter will always succeed and don't really have a purpose.

Hence, what remains is just finding out the value of the generic type of each container. You could do this e.g. using runtime introspection.

Setup:

```
/* Container and protocol setup */
class MyClass : CustomStringConvertible {
    var foo : Int = 1
    var description: String { return "MyClass().foo = \(foo)"}
}

protocol MyUniqueGenericContainer {
    func printMyVar()
}

struct Container<T> : MyUniqueGenericContainer {
    var myVar : T

    // MARK: MyUniqueGenericContainer
    func printMyVar() {
        print(myVar)
    }
}
```

Example using runtime introspection to find container value type and call blueprinted method `printMyVar()`:

```
let value1 = Container<Int>(myVar: 1)
let value2 = Container<MyClass>(myVar: MyClass())
let value3 = Container<String>(myVar: "one")
let value4 = "Foobar"

let values : [Any] = [value1, value2, value3, value4]

for (i, value) in values.enumerate() {
    var isKnown = true

    switch value {
    case let val as MyUniqueGenericContainer:
        let valueMirror = Mirror(reflecting: value).children.filter{ $0.label == "myVar" }
        if let containerMyVar = valueMirror.first?.value {
            let containerType = containerMyVar.dynamicType
            print("Element #\(i+1) type: Container<\(containerType)>,",
                ".printMyVar(): ", terminator: "")
            val.printMyVar()
        }
        else { isKnown = false }
    case _ : isKnown = false
    }
    if !isKnown {
        print("Element #\(i+1) not of Container<T> type")
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
/* Element #1 type: Container<Int>, .printMyVar(): 1
   Element #2 type: Container<MyClass>, .printMyVar(): MyClass().foo = 1
   Element #3 type: Container<String>, .printMyVar(): one
   Element #4 not of Container<T> type                                    */
```

Comment: Hi dfri, thank you very much. Using reflection allows me to find the containerType. But for 2., is it also possible to cast the content to the containerType, i.e. getting the variable for `myVar`? Or would such a cast be impossible? Let's say `Container<T>` has a member function to print out `myVar`, I would like to call that member function during the iteration.

Comment: @Se7enDays Sure, simplest way is to add a function blueprint to the protocol `MyUniqueGenericContainer` (that your container class conforms to). Updated my example above; the `case` now uses conditional assignment of the value (`case let ... as ...`, which includes type check) as compared to the earlier type check only (`case is ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining:

```
if let value = value as? ContainerA<XYZ> {
    // value is now of type ContainerA<XYZ>
} else {
    // can't cast
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that if I know the type XYZ. In my case however I dont know it. I could have a list with ContainerA<B>, ContainerA<C> and ContainerA<D> etc - and I want to find the objects of classes B, C, D, etc

Answer (score 0):

Here you go…

```
switch value {
    case is ContainerA<A>:
        ...
    case is ContainerA<B>:
        ...
    case is ContainerA<C>:           
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

or

```
if let value = value as? ContainerA<A> {
    // value is now of type ContainerA<A>
} else if let value = value as? ContainerA<B> {
    // value is now of type ContainerA<B>
} else if let value = value as? ContainerA<C> {
    // value is now of type ContainerA<C>
} else {
    // can't cast
}
```